# swipe right on touch to toggle class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible, with jquery mobile or jquery to have a swipe event that changes the class something?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").swiperight(function(event){
        $('.main-content').toggleClass('.swiped');
    });
});
```

Would you use jquery or jquery mobile for this sort of thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.main-content').toggleClass('.swiped');
//                              ^ not dot please!
```

Should be:

```
$('.main-content').toggleClass('swiped');
```

BTW, I think without a plugin jQuery mobile gives only this API:

```
$("body").on('swiperight', function(){});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('swiperight', function(){
        $('.sidebarholder').toggleClass('show-sidebar');
    });
    });

This doesn't work :/

Comment: Without `$(document).ready(function() {` @andy `$("body").on('swiperight', function(){ $('.sidebarholder').toggleClass('show-sidebar'); });`

Comment: @andy, do you have jQuery mobile...?

Comment: Yeah, got it working now with jq mobile.

The problem is, it puts some sort of overlay on my page? ui-mobile-viewport-transitioning? and it screws things up.

Comment: And what do you want to do with your class?

Comment: Just toggle a class when there's a swipe, nothing fancy.

Comment: http://www.codingjack.com/playground/swipe/ Found this plugin that takes the swipe stuff from jquery mobile.